# Vuetify | Values does not persist using DOM methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, selenium-webdriver, vuetify.js, cucumberjs

I am using `Vuetify` form fields like `v-text-field` or `v-text-area` and I have a use case in which am trying to directly update the value of the input fields using DOM methods `document.querySelector` directly.

And the issue am facing is whenever the focus is changed the field values for example `v-text-area` becomes blank or reset to original value.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field v-model="msg" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. Refer the above code or go to this [link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqLrq7VUTLWM9EzNFUCMUz1jJRiATjNBLA=).
2. Open the Console (dev tools) and simply try to add value using: `document.querySelector('#input-0').value = 'test'`

*Result:*
The value is applied to the textfield but once you click somewhere or focus is changed then the value is reset.

I suspect this is because of state. But is there any way to achieve the behaviour using DOM methods and attributes ?

**Purpose behind trying the DOM Methods:**
The reason am trying to this experiment is because in my **selenium** automation tool. I want to programmatically type some text inside the form fields. I know there is a method provided by selenium `sendkeys`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).sendKeys("Test");
```

But this takes time when I want to add some large text. So, I am trying to achieve this behaviour using JavascriptExecutor:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[1].value=arguments[0]", "'" + text + "'", element);
```

But, it seems the above code does not work because of the DOM methods issue mentioned on the top.

Let me know if there is any solution in vuetify or Selenium

Comment: Since vue's v-model directive creates an event listener to onInput, you could try dispatching the event manually and see if that updates vue. ```document.querySelector('#input-0').dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));```

Comment: If you hope to achieve anything near an actual user experience in your script, don't do this. No user is going to input text using JS so you are shortcutting around the functionality of the site which may put the site in a bad/unknown state. It may be slower but it's the way to do it properly.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Your suggestion worked for me

Comment: @JeffC yes its true that this JS functionality is a workaround. But this is the only way I think which is usable against the slowness of `sendkeys`. It is possible that I will be stuck on some another issue after using the Js executor, but I won't know without doing such experiments